# Back-button direct to login page instead of phone(homepage)

Tags: firebase-authentication, ionic4

I need help.

When user login into the app, I tried to use back-button on android phone, to see if its go to login page or android phone homepage. The result was it direct me to login page.

I think its suppose to go to homepage of the phone rather than login page. Because its not a logout button right.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NavController for this.

```
import {  NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(
    private navCtrl: NavController
) {}

onLogin(){
   this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('homepage');
}
```

navigateRoot method remove the backhistory of app.

Comment: Where do I implement these? app.component.ts or login.page.ts?

Comment: you have to add this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('homepage'); this line, on your user login method. If you are using router to navigate from login to homepage, replace router with this navCtrl.navigateRoot('homepage') .